# How to get definition of word from website?

Tags: c

Proper way to pull data from website dyamically?

Comment: Look whether Dictionary.com provides and API for this; This might be the fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a webservice like [`Big Huge Thesaurus`](http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php)

- You can easily send HTTP requests using [`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).
- There should be plenty of libraries available for parsing [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/).
- For XML, [`Expat`](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) and [`libxml`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) are popular ones.

Comment: Dictionary.com has API for its site

Comment: Are you asking me or you're adding to the answer ? I could not find any readily available reference to their API from their home page at least.